# How can I substract 253 from 175(175-253) through 2's complement method?

Tags: algorithm, scientific-computing, computation, computer-algebra-systems

For 2's complement, substraction process by computer.

176-253=176+(-253)

176=10110000

253=11111101

253(inverse)=00000010

253(complement)=00000010+1=00000011

-253=253(complement)=00000011

176+(-253)=10110000+00000011=10110011=179?

but in fact 176-253=-77

is anybody tell me what's wrong here?

Comment: With 8 bits you can only represent numbers from -128 to 127 inclusive in 2's complement. Both your numbers lie outside that range.

Comment: but if I exchange like this(253-176), it is work, and get the correct answer.

Comment: 179 and -77 are the same in 8 bit 2's complement

Answer (score 4):

With 8 bits you can only represent numbers from -128 to 127 inclusive in 2's complement. Both your numbers lie outside that range. You would need at least nine bits to do the calculation you want to do.

In 2's complement the most significant bit (MSB, the first bit from the left), indicates the sign, 1 for negative numbers and 0 for non-negative numbers. The value:

```
00000011
```

is not -253, but is 3.

Doing your calculation in 9 bits yields:

```
176 = 010110000
253 = 011111101

253(inverse) = 100000010
253(complement) = 100000010+1=100000011

-253 = 253(complement) = 100000011
176+(-253) = 010110000 + 100000011 = 110110011 = -77
```

Note that all the negative numbers have MSB=1 and all the non-negative numbers have MSB=0.

Comment: but it seems 010110000+100000011=110110011=-179, is not 176-253=-77,why?

Comment: It seems you now take the MSB as the sign and then calculate the rest of the number as a normal positive number. I.e. `110110011 = -(10110011) = -179`. That is *not* correct. The MSB tells you the sign, but to get the value you still need to invert and add 1. I.e. `110110011 = -(001001100 + 1) = -(001001101) = -77`.

Comment: but as we already make invert before sum, 253(inverse) = 100000010,why do it again here?

Comment: Because MSB=1 indicates that we are dealing with a negative number. To convert a negative number in 2's complement to the equivalent positive number, you invert all bits and add 1. Think of it this way, suppose we would have added 0 to -253. Then the 2's complement number we end up with is the same as the one we started with, namely `100000011`, we would still need to convert that result back to get our original -253.